# get selected rows based on column names (Multidimensional Array) : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Multidimensional array as shown below:

```
[
["1","success","5"],
["2","success","5"],
["3","success","5"],
["4","fail","5"],
["5","fail;","5"],
["6","fail","5"],
["7","success","5"],
["8","fail","5"],
];
```

what I need is to select particular rows based on the `success` and `fail` type. which means for eaxmple i have to only get the data whose second column is named `success`

I have written a code but it gives me values in separate arrays.
I want the data in this format

```
 [
    ["1","success","5"],
    ["2","success","5"],
    ["3","success","5"],
    ["7","success","5"],
]
```

The code that I have tried is the folllowing:

```
  var success = [];
     for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {
        if(arr[i][1] =='success')
        {
         success = [arr[i]];
         console.log(success);
        }
     }
```

I want all the data in single array.
Here is the Fiddle Link that I Tried: https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/09zchjak/

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're *replacing* the value in `success` on every match. Instead, you want to *add to* it: `success.push(arr[i])`. (But as the answer below says, `filter` is for this specific purpose.)

Comment: I think I can help you to solve your problem sir, how to discuss sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const data = [
  ['1', 'success', '5'],
  ['2', 'success', '5'],
  ['3', 'success', '5'],
  ['4', 'fail', '5'],
  ['5', 'fail;', '5'],
  ['6', 'fail', '5'],
  ['7', 'success', '5'],
  ['8', 'fail', '5'],
];
const success = data.filter((x) => x[1] === 'success');
console.log(success);
```